# Custom form field for Foreign key model field in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model form:

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    Meta:
        model = Bar
        fields = ('baz', 'description')
```

And my Bar class is:

```
class Bar:
    baz = models.ForeignKey(Baz)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

The problem is that **Baz class** has many entries and as [django's documentation says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types) it uses [**ModelChoiceField**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField) for baz field that's very inefficient:

> **class ModelChoiceField(**kwargs)**
>
> Allows the selection of a single model object, suitable for representing a foreign key. Note that the default widget for ModelChoiceField becomes impractical when the number of entries increases. You should avoid using it for more than 100 items.

The problem is that I couldn't find how to avoid using it.

In another word I want to know how to change default mapping between **Model field** to **Form field** and use another field for Foreign key field?

Also in my special case I just want to **show** baz field in my ModelForm and be disabled, so in addition to inefficiency problem of ModelChoiceField it's not proper for this usage too.

Comment: you can create a widget class that fits your needs and link it to the ModelChoiceField

Comment: Does using custom widget solve the problem? I mean It's still using ModelChoiceField with just another [html representation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/).

Comment: I guess they're not saying that it's not efficient, but that it's just 'impractical' to select one entry out of 100s of items

Comment: @skndstry In my opinion in addition to being impractical to select on entry, It's also inefficient because it does query and select all objects from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution that satisfy my needs but I'll accept any more general answer that explain what's best practice for avoiding ModelChoiceField when it is needed :)

I just need to change FooForm to:

```
class BuzCustomField(forms.CharField):

    def clean(self, value):
        """
        Validates the given value and returns its "cleaned" value as an
        appropriate Python object.

        Raises ValidationError for any errors.
        """
        value = self.to_python(value)
        value = Buz.objects.get(value)
        self.validate(value)
        self.run_validators(value)
        return value

class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    baz = forms.BuzCustomField()

    Meta:
        model = Bar
        fields = ('baz', 'description')
```

Again I mention that I just needed to show **baz** so using BuzCustomField will not be appropriate in all cases.